# Unable to open datepicker after pressing esc

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I'm having angularjs date picker on read-only textbox,
on clicking of the text box, date picker pops up,
pressing esc closes the date picker but again clicking on the text box does not open the date picker.

we have to click outside the box and again clicking inside the box opens the date picker.
is there any way, I can open the date picker without clicking outside.

Answer (score 0):

on click of text field set $('#id').focus();